# Getting error when run a .vbs file thorugh ADODB.Connection

Tags: excel, vbscript, ado, adodb, vba

The script below formed to find out those rows which don't have the date values in increasing order.But when I ran the code getting an `ERROR` saying as `No value given one or more required parameters`

**CODE**

```
Option Explicit

Dim conn, cmd, rs
Dim clauses(36), i
Dim xlApp, xlBook

Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
With conn
.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
.ConnectionString = "Data Source=""D:\WIPData\AravoMacro\Finalscripts\GE_Wing_To_Wing_Report.xlsx"";" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes"""
.Open
End With

For i = 0 To 36
clauses(i) = "[Task" & i + 1 & " Start Date] < [Task" & i + 2 & " Start Date]"
Next

Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [GEWingToWingMay25$] WHERE " & Join(clauses, " OR ")
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
Set rs = cmd.Execute

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = True
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
xlBook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset cmd.Execute
```

Can anyone help me out here?

**EDIT**

[image: Screenshot of the SQL text]

Thanks,

**EDIT1**

Now I tried this

```
      Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
 'cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [GEWingToWingMay25$] WHERE " & Join(clauses, " OR ") 
  cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [GEWingToWingMay25$] WHERE " & "#2012/10/01# > #2012/10/015#"
  MsgBox(cmd.CommandText)
  cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
  Set rs = cmd.Execute
```

Getting an error `class doesn't support Automation`

**Snpashot2**

[image: Excel Table snap]

**EDIT3**

I updated as below :

```
      cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [GEWingToWingMay25$] WHERE #" &     CDate([Task1StartDate]) & "# > #" & CDate([Task2StartDate]) _
 "# > #" & CDate([Task3 Start Date]) & "# > #" & CDate([Task4 Start Date]) _
 "# > #" & CDate([Task5 Start Date]) & "# > #" & CDate([Task6 Start Date]) _
 "# > #" & CDate([Task7 Start Date]) & "# > #" & CDate([Task8 Start Date]) _
 "# > #" & CDate([Task9 Start Date]) & "# > #" & CDate([Task10 Start Date]) _
 "# > #" & CDate([Task11 Start Date]) & "# > #" & CDate([Task12 Start Date]) _
 "# > #" & CDate([Task13 Start Date]) & "# > #" & CDate([Task14 Start Date]) _
 "# > #" & CDate([Task15 Start Date]) & "# > #" & CDate([Task16 Start Date]) _
 "# > #" & CDate([Task17 Start Date]) & "# > #" & CDate([Task18 Start Date]) _
 "# > #" & CDate([Task19 Start Date]) & "# > #" & CDate([Task20 Start Date]) _
 "# > #" & CDate([Task21 Start Date]) & "# > #" & CDate([Task22 Start Date]) _
 "# > #" & CDate([Task23 Start Date]) & "# > #" & CDate([Task24 Start Date]) _
 "# > #" & CDate([Task25 Start Date]) & "# > #" & CDate([Task26 Start Date]) _
 "# > #" & CDate([Task27 Start Date]) & "# > #" & CDate([Task28 Start Date]) _
 "# > #" & CDate([Task29 Start Date]) & "# > #" & CDate([Task30 Start Date]) _
 "# > #" & CDate([Task31 Start Date]) & "# > #" & CDate([Task32 Start Date]) _
 "# > #" & CDate([Task33 Start Date]) & "# > #" & CDate([Task34 Start Date]) _
 "# > #" & CDate([Task35 Start Date]) & "# > #" & CDate([Task36 Start Date]) & "#;"
```

**EDIT4** As the [Google link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819#Connect) suggests that if `HDR` is set to yes,then the excel sheet should have first row as field level labeling, and my excel has that. but then why the error is coming any idea please?

*Updated Code*

```
    Option Explicit

    Dim conn, cmd, rs
    Dim clauses(34), i
    Dim xlApp, xlBook
    Dim tempDate,LenDate


    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    With conn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=""D:\AravoVB\GE_Wing_To_Wing_Report.xlsx"";" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes"""
    .Open
    End With

    For i = 0 To 34
    clauses(i) = "[Task" & i + 1 & " Start Date] > [Task" & i + 2 & " Start Date]"
    tempDate=tempDate & "[Task" & i + 1 & " Start Date],"
    Next

    Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT " & tempDate &" FROM [GEWingToWingMay25$] WHERE [Business Process ID] NOT IN (" & "SELECT [Business Process ID] FROM [GEWingToWingMay25$] WHERE " & Join(clauses, " AND ") & ")"
    MsgBox(cmd.CommandText)
    cmd.ActiveConnection = conn 
    Set rs = cmd.Execute

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlApp.Visible = True
    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
    xlBook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset cmd.Execute
```

now all the `start date` has not values for each row,Thus SQL Query inside the `IN` operator not returning any values,thus outer SQL query giving all the data.So any idea how to ignore such `Null values` inside the SQL query `where` clause evaluations. Any Idea?

Comment: you seem to get going well now ;) the possible reason for the error: can you wrap your dates with pound key e.g. #2012/12/21#. So I suggest you to just put two static dates with # in your SQL query and test if it's working. If working, then you can try to add the parameter adjusting the string.

Comment: @bonCodigo when I have a teacher like you,student should increase his performance,to increase his teachers' respect!! :-) I didn't.how should I do so,in my large data excel.Please advice!

Comment: @bonCodigo Error line is `Set rs = cmd.Execute`.

Comment: Your SQL query has syntax error so it can't execute... Assuming you have data in the table, you can try the following: `SELECT * FROM [GEWingToWingMay25$] WHERE  [Task12StartDate] > #2012/10/01#` . Can you explain give a sample of what values in `[Task12StartDate]`?

Comment: @TukaiRakshit Can you a `debug.print` after you've set the CommandText option as i'd like to see what the full statement reads?

Comment: @bonCodigo Yes, the date values are in the format `09/01/2012 01:11:11 PM`. Si this the information you asked from me?

Comment: @MattDonnan sure I am doing,give me some moments!

Comment: @MattDonnan Please see my edit. I attached the screenshot.I used `MsgBox(cmd.CommandText)`.

Comment: @TukaiRakshit Please try to do one plain SQL string and test if it works. Your query is perhaps even above the query string limit I am afriad...

Comment: @TukaiRakshit That is one monster SQL, I'm with BonCodigo here, it may exceed the char's your allowed.

Comment: Guess the best you could do, do some cross validations before sending these multiple date comparisons to your query. Or else do multiple validation queries (query table then query on resulting query). My God it's gonna get nasty...

Comment: @MattDonnan please see my **EDIT1** and advice me how to correct this,so that my code success!

Comment: @TukaiRakshit in your EDIT1, you don't need `" & "` to be put in when you are sending the pure plain SQL query.

Comment: Are you able to attach a screen-shot of your excel file, we may be able to devise a better solution?

Comment: @MattDonnan I doubt he can attach here. But he could show us a sample of the data sheet ;) He could do most of the data filtering in a hidden sheet by small parts. Then call up a SQL if he really needs...

Comment: @bonCodigo That's what I meant, not the actual file but a screen-shot of the data.

Comment: @bonCodigo please see the second screenshot!

Comment: @MattDonnan please see the second screenshot! here i have tried to show you guys how my data looks like,But all the task details are stored in the same format as it is for Task#1 and Task#2.

Comment: @bonCodigo humm nice idea! :-) ... no option to do so.All i need to do with this spread sheet!

Comment: @TukaiRakshit This comment train is getting a little long, do all the rows have differening number of tasks; some less than 36 or do they all meet the full amount?

Comment: @MattDonnan Good Question!! No not needed all the 36 start dates should be there, and in reality it is not so.data varies between 1- 36.For each row it is not completely filled up,but for some rows it is

Comment: Why not do a `sub` and get all the tasks and their dates in to a sheet. Or just create a pivot based on task and dates. Sort it and perhpas that would give u an idea. BTW with your recent edit, did you try with just two dates in the SQL string?

Comment: @TukaiRakshit I think a function is the way to go, please see my answer.

Comment: @bonCodigo any idea you want to share or any fix you want to apply here?

Comment: Can anyone please help me here?

Answer (score 0):

Steps to debug your issue:

1. Check in `Watch Window` what kind of a data is produced by `[Task" & i + 1 & " Start Date]`. It's supposed to be column in your table. However it doesn't seem to return a proper date. Once it's in order, you may go to the next step.
2. Try to send a plain SQL Query string and test whether it gets executed.
   e.g. as per my comment.

---

**Editted:**

It doesn't look great the way you construct your table fields...

`"SELECT * FROM [GEWingToWingMay25$] WHERE [Task12 Start Date] > [Task13StartDate];"`

Don't forget the semi-colon to end the query string.

I wish I could put this all in a comment. Anyway give it a try and let us know. The above line is just a sample.

Comment: please see my **EDIT1** and advice me what to do next?

Comment: Let me do it as you suggested!

Comment: please see my **EDIT**, but from that _forst_ of hashes I am getting an error `Expected end of statement`. Where it is couldn't find out,please guide me!`

Comment: with the statement `cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [GEWingToWingMay25$] WHERE #" & CDate([Task12 Start Date]) & "# > #" & CDate([Task13 Start Date]) & "#;"` i got error that `Variable is undefined: "Task12 Start Date"`

Comment: but it is in the Excel header column. All the column labeling are done in the 3rd row. From 4th row onwards raw data begins!

Comment: Any idea would you like to suggest me?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a different approach, I've written this function, create a new module in excel and add this:

```
Public Function InSequence()

Dim dtOld   As Date
Dim dtNew   As Date
Dim i       As Long
Dim flg     As Boolean

    flg = True
    i = 2

    Do Until Cells(ActiveCell.Row, i) & "" = ""
        If InStr(Cells(1, i), "Start Date") > 0 Then
            dtOld = IIf(dtNew = 0, Cells(ActiveCell.Row, i), dtNew)
            dtNew = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, i)
            If dtNew < dtOld Then flg = False
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    InSequence = flg

End Function
```

Then on your data sheet, insert a column before column A and call the function as such:

```
=InSequence()
```

It returns true if the dates on that row are in sequential order and false if they are not

Comment: my excel data has been pulled by the scripts from another sheet,so I can't create any function on any column manually.Because all are in dynamic nature!Its good to see you gave one idea,but I need a VBScript one version as EXCEL vba is not allowed for me to code.

Comment: Ok, can you please confirm the number of columns across, and the amount of rows the spreadsheet has?

Comment: number of columns 154 and currently it has 2020 rows, thus general looping and searching is too time consuming,to produce the desired output. Thus I was trying some advanced one,like the above code

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of selecting all the data into a dynamic array and then looping that to build the output, I'm not sure whether with that many columns though whether it is a good idea. To be honest, even if you were designing a database solution instead, 154 columns is a poor design fundamentally; you're unfortunately trying to make the best of a bad situation, I suggest going back to the beginning and getting any approval you may need to seriously overhaul the process.

Comment: now that is not possible,i have to go this way, as the project is going on and I am very close to deliver,but such 2-3 scripts causes some bottlenecks for that.Please save me here.

Comment: @TukaiRakshit I'm sorry but I don't have any idea's left, not been able to change late in a project is unfortunate but that's why you need to think about and outline these things at the start to whom it may concern, I wish you the best of luck, and please answer the question yourself if you get to the solution.

Comment: Still I am trying to do it....lets See.The problem i faced here got removed,now opened different post,if you want can see it.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001035/error-in-nvl-function-is-there-any-equivalent-function-like-nvl#comment19332328_14001035