# Error in NVL function,is there any equivalent function like NVL

Tags: excel, vbscript, ado, adodb, vba

The below code is written VBScript.but the line `Set rs = cmd.Execute` throwing an error saying that `NVL` is not defined. So can you suggest an equivalent of such "NVL"

```
        Option Explicit

        Dim conn, cmd, rs
         Dim clauses(34), i
    Dim xlApp, xlBook
    Dim tempDate,LenDate


    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    With conn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=""D:\AravoVB\GE_Wing_To_Wing_Report - Copy.xlsx"";" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes"""
    .Open
    End With
    tempDate="[Business Process ID],"
    For i = 0 To 34
    clauses(i) = "[Task" & i + 1 & " Start Date] > [Task" & i + 2 & " Start Date]"
    tempDate=tempDate & "NVL([Task" & i + 1 & " Start Date],sysdate+"& i &"),"
    Next
    LenDate=Len(tempDate)-1
    tempDate=Mid(tempDate,1,LenDate)
    MsgBox(tempDate)

    Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT " & tempDate &" FROM [GEWingToWingMay25$] WHERE [Business Process ID] NOT IN (" & "SELECT [Business Process ID] FROM [GEWingToWingMay25$] WHERE " & Join(clauses, " AND ") & ")"
    MsgBox(cmd.CommandText)
    cmd.ActiveConnection = conn 
    Set rs = cmd.Execute

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xlApp.Visible = True
    Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
    xlBook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset cmd.Execute
```

[image: Error in NZ]

***EDIT:***

```
      For i = 0 To 1
      clauses(i) = "IIf(IsNull([Task" & i + 1 & " Start Date]),sysdate+"& i &",[Task" & i + 1 & " Start Date]) > IIf(IsNull([Task" & i + 2 & " Start Date]),sysdate+"& i &",[Task" & i + 2 & " Start Date])"
'tempDate=tempDate & "NVL([Task" & i + 1 & " Start Date],sysdate+"& i &"),"
      Next
```

***Error*** : Getting `No value given for one or more required parameters`

`MsgBox(cmd.CommandText):`

[image: ADO Error]

[image: ADO Error2]

***SQL***

```
         `SELECT * FROM [GEWingToWingMay25$] WHERE [Business Process ID] NOT IN (SELECT [Business Process ID] FROM [GEWingToWingMay25$] WHERE IIf(IsNull([Task1 Start Date]),Date()+0,[Task1 Start Date]) < IIf(IsNull([Task2 Start Date]),Date()+0,[Task2 Start Date]) OR IIf(IsNull([Task2 Start Date]),Date()+1,[Task2 Start Date]) < IIf(IsNull([Task3 Start Date]),Date()+1,[Task3 Start Date]) OR IIf(IsNull([Task3 Start Date]),Date()+2,[Task3 Start Date]) < IIf(IsNull([Task4 Start Date]),Date()+2,[Task4 Start Date]) OR IIf(IsNull([Task4 Start Date]),Date()+3,[Task4 Start Date]) < IIf(IsNull([Task5 Start Date]),Date()+3,[Task5 Start Date]) OR IIf(IsNull([Task5 Start Date]),Date()+4,[Task5 Start Date]) < IIf(IsNull([Task6 Start Date]),Date()+4,[Task6 Start Date]) OR IIf(IsNull([Task6 Start Date]),Date()+5,[Task6 Start Date]) < IIf(IsNull([Task7 Start Date]),Date()+5,[Task7 Start Date]) OR IIf(IsNull([Task7 Start Date]),Date()+6,[Task7 Start Date]) < IIf(IsNull([Task8 Start Date]),Date()+6,[Task8 Start Date]) OR IIf(IsNull([Task8 Start Date]),Date()+7,[Task8 Start Date]) < IIf(IsNull([Task9 Start Date]),Date()+7,[Task9 Start Date]) OR IIf(IsNull([Task9 Start Date]),Date()+8,[Task9 Start Date]) < IIf(IsNull([Task10 Start Date]),Date()+8,[Task10 Start Date]) OR IIf(IsNull([Task10 Start Date]),Date()+9,[Task10 Start Date]) < IIf(IsNull([Task11 Start Date]),Date()+9,[Task11 Start Date]) OR IIf(IsNull([Task11 Start Date]),Date()+10,[Task11 Start Date]) < IIf(IsNull([Task12 Start Date]),Date()+10,[Task12 Start Date]) OR IIf(IsNull([Task12 Start Date]),Date()+11,[Task12 Start Date]) < IIf(IsNull([Task13 Start Date]),Date()+11,[Task13 Start Date]) OR IIf(IsNull([Task13 Start Date]),Date()+12,[Task13 Start Date]) < IIf(IsNull([Task14 Start Date]),Date()+12,[Task14 Start Date]) OR IIf(IsNull([Task14 Start Date]),Date()+13,[Task14 Start Date]) < IIf(IsNull([Task15 Start Date]),Date()+13,[Task15 Start Date]) OR IIf(IsNull([Task15 Start Date]),Date()+14,[Task15 Start Date]) < IIf(IsNull([Task16 Start Date]),Date()+14,[Task16 Start Date]) OR IIf(IsNull([Task16 Start Date]),Date()+15,[Task16 Start Date]) < IIf(IsNull([Task17 Start Date]),Date()+15,[Task17 Start Date]) OR IIf(IsNull([Task17 Start Date]),Date()+16,[Task17 Start Date]) < IIf(IsNull([Task18 Start Date]),Date()+16,[Task18 Start Date]) OR IIf(IsNull([Task18 Start Date]),Date()+17,[Task18 Start Date]) < IIf(IsNull([Task19 Start Date]),Date()+17,[Task19 Start Date]) OR IIf(IsNull([Task19 Start Date]),Date()+18,[Task19 Start Date]) < IIf(IsNull([Task20 Start Date]),Date()+18,[Task20 Start Date]) OR IIf(IsNull([Task20 Start Date]),Date()+19,[Task20 Start Date]) < IIf(IsNull([Task21 Start Date]),Date()+19,[Task21 Start Date]) OR IIf(IsNull([Task21 Start Date]),Date()+20,[Task21 Start Date]) < IIf(IsNull([Task22 Start Date]),Date()+20,[Task22 Start Date]) OR IIf(IsNull([Task22 Start Date]),Date()+21,[Task22 Start Date]) < IIf(IsNull([Task23 Start Date]),Date()+21,[Task23 Start Date]) OR IIf(IsNull([Task23 Start Date]),Date()+22,[Task23 Start Date]) < IIf(IsNull([Task24 Start Date]),Date()+22,[Task24 Start Date]) OR IIf(IsNull([Task24 Start Date]),Date()+23,[Task24 Start Date]) < IIf(IsNull([Task25 Start Date]),Date()+23,[Task25 Start Date]) OR IIf(IsNull([Task25 Start Date]),Date()+24,[Task25 Start Date]) < IIf(IsNull([Task26 Start Date]),Date()+24,[Task26 Start Date]) OR IIf(IsNull([Task26 Start Date]),Date()+25,[Task26 Start Date]) < IIf(IsNull([Task27 Start Date]),Date()+25,[Task27 Start Date]) OR IIf(IsNull([Task27 Start Date]),Date()+26,[Task27 Start Date]) < IIf(IsNull([Task28 Start Date]),Date()+26,[Task28 Start Date]) OR IIf(IsNull([Task28 Start Date]),Date()+27,[Task28 Start Date]) < IIf(IsNull([Task29 Start Date]),Date()+27,[Task29 Start Date]) OR IIf(IsNull([Task29 Start Date]),Date()+28,[Task29 Start Date]) < IIf(IsNull([Task30 Start Date]),Date()+28,[Task30 Start Date]) OR IIf(IsNull([Task30 Start Date]),Date()+29,[Task30 Start Date]) < IIf(IsNull([Task31 Start Date]),Date()+29,[Task31 Start Date]) OR IIf(IsNull([Task31 Start Date]),Date()+30,[Task31 Start Date]) < IIf(IsNull([Task32 Start Date]),Date()+30,[Task32 Start Date]) OR IIf(IsNull([Task32 Start Date]),Date()+31,[Task32 Start Date]) < IIf(IsNull([Task33 Start Date]),Date()+31,[Task33 Start Date]) OR IIf(IsNull([Task33 Start Date]),Date()+32,[Task33 Start Date]) < IIf(IsNull([Task34 Start Date]),Date()+32,[Task34 Start Date]) OR IIf(IsNull([Task34 Start Date]),Date()+33,[Task34 Start Date]) < IIf(IsNull([Task35 Start Date]),Date()+33,[Task35 Start Date]) OR IIf(IsNull([Task35 Start Date]),Date()+34,[Task35 Start Date]) < IIf(IsNull([Task36 Start Date]),Date()+34,[Task36 Start Date]))`
```

**EDIT**

OptiOn Explicit

```
Dim conn, cmd, rs
     Dim clauses(34), i
Dim xlApp, xlBook
Dim tempDate,LenDate


Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
With conn
.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
.ConnectionString = "Data Source=""D:\AravoVB\Final Scripts\GE_Wing_To_Wing_Report - Copy.xlsx"";" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes"""
.Open
End With
'tempDate=""
For i = 0 To 34
clauses(i) = "IIf(IsNull([Task" & i + 1 & " Start Date]),Date()+"& i &",[Task" & i + 1 & " Start Date]) < IIf(IsNull([Task" & i + 2 & " Start Date]),Date()+"& i &",[Task" & i + 2 & " Start Date])"
tempDate=tempDate & "NVL([Task" & i + 1 & " Start Date],Date()+"& i &"),"
Next
'LenDate=Len(tempDate)-1
'tempDate=Mid(tempDate,1,LenDate)
MsgBox(tempDate)

Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [GEWingToWingMay25$] WHERE [Business Process ID] NOT IN (" & "SELECT [Business Process ID] FROM [GEWingToWingMay25$] WHERE " & Join(clauses, " OR ") & ")"
MsgBox(cmd.CommandText)
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn 
Set rs = cmd.Execute

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = True
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
xlBook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset cmd.Execute
'xlBook.Sheets(1).Cells(1,25).Value=cmd.CommandText
```

Comment: I could be wrong but the equivalent I guess is `NZ()` ? Syntax: `NZ(field, valuehereif_field_isnull)`

Comment: @SiddharthRout NZ returns an error saying `Undefined function 'NZ'` in expression.

Comment: Perhaps Nz requires a library reference to be enabled....when used in Excel...just a thought.

Comment: @bonCodigo this script fails due to no values in some date columns,for which sql where clause couldn't evaluate properly,returns all rows,which is not the purpose! thus tried something different so that SQL compares till the Date columns have values in it.In this regard any suggestions from you?

Comment: @bonCodigo any idea on my above statement?

Comment: Can you post the `debug.print tempdate` and `debug.print` command text? what value have you set as default date?

Comment: @bonCodigo defaul date is `sysdate` i set.which column has no date value they would be set as `sysdate + i`.

Comment: @TukaiRakshit what is the use of these two lines? `LenDate=Len(tempDate)-1`  `tempDate=Mid(tempDate,1,LenDate)` . Looking at teh debug print, it seem your `where` caluse is left with a null... See the update in the answer - putting it there as too long to enter as a comment.

Comment: @bonCodigo ignore those lines... see my edit.I used `date()` instead of `sysdate`.Now the errors are gone,but it seems that the `Date()` not meeting its purpose!

Comment: As date is not returning its current date, also result of that select query couldn't ignore records which has date in in creasing order,as NULL values making the condition to `TRUE` and the overall purpose got failed.

Comment: @Tukai Rakshit Can you append above `CommandText` into your question? So it could be copied as text to edit?

Comment: @bonCodigo I am done,please see the description!

Comment: Any help in this post please?

Answer (score 5):

### This answers your question on NVL, Nz Equivalent.

Just use `IIF(IsNull())..`

Because `Nz` is only supported within Access.

[Here is the reference article :](http://ewbi.blogs.com/develops/2007/11/why-no-nz-via-j.html)

The only non-intrinsic SQL functions available in JET database queries outside of Access are those found in the VBA library, whose objects are exposed for use via the underlying JET database engine (with consideration for certainsandbox restrictions). You can perform some crazy-complex calculations in your queries using functions like VBA'sIPmt() and PPmt(), **and you can evaluate conditional logic using VBA's IIf(), but you cannot Nz() a column to overcome a Null value, because Nz() is a method of the Access.Application object**.

So what are the alternatives to Nz()? Well, you could combine VBA's IIf() and IsNull() to do the same thing:

```
select IIf(IsNull(SomePossiblyNullField), '', SomePossiblyNullField) 
from SomeTable
```

Or, if you're dealing with potentially Null string values, you can take advantage of the non-conforming JET SQL syntax's explicit concatenation operator (&), which it shares with VBA, and pound an empty string onto your value. The following query will produce the same result as the previous one:

```
select SomePossiblyNullField & '' 
from SomeTable
```

I say non-conforming because in most cases combining Null with anything via an operator results in a Null; however, the concatenation operator works differently, treating Nulls like empty strings. Mathematical operators, like +, -, *, etc., do conform with standard tri-value Null logic in that their application to any Null value results in a Null expression, including the unfortunate case where + is applied to strings, which JET's SQL syntax and VBA still allow for historical reasons.

---

### Here are possible reasons for the error: NO VALUE GIVEN FOR ONE OR MORE PARAMETERS.

[Reference article:](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=275002&highlight=newc0m0r)

- Reason 1: If the worksheet contain columnnames in the first row or not. If yes then the connection string should include the Extended Property `HDR=YES` otherwise to `HDR=NO`. **Which you already have set.**
- Reason 2: SQL Expressions and column names used in `Where` clause. This seems to be the most possible cause of your error.

Can you edit your query string as the following:
`SYSDATE` needs to be treated as an Excel Date() and add days using `DateSerial()` and then maintain the date format using `Format()`.

`Format(DateSerial(Year(Date),Month(Date),Day(Date) + i), "yyyy-mm-dd")`

AS for the `where` clause, may be it's best to use a `Switch` statment and make sure add a default condition such as `Date < Date + 1` or as it deems.

Comment: `..Start Date],sysdate+"& i &"),"` do you see the comma `,` here? Can you remove it? Then try out `Nz` to confirm it doesn't work and use `IIF(IsNull())` to confirm if it works... I am on mobile so eager to hear the output ;-)

Comment: beacuse date() function not doing what I expected,i added it to handle column which has no date values for records,but the code still fetching those as bad data,which should not if date() works ther.

Comment: Either IIF(IsNull(var),"",var) is not working or date() not working!

Comment: any workaround of this code,which can at least work for me would you suggest?

Comment: Thanks, this answer was helpful in deciding whether to use Nz() or IIf(IsNull()) to assign a value to my nulls.