# Excel null date columns are needs to be updated by ADODB and vbscript

Tags: excel, vbscript, ado, adodb, vba

I am working MS Excel-2010.I have an excel sheet like below:

```
Process#       requirementrcvd     designdate     codingdate      test1 date      test2 date   deliverdate

  11           10/11/2009          12/12/2009     02/02/2011      02/03/2011      09/03/2011   10/04/2011
  12           10/11/2010          12/12/2011     15/02/2012      
  13           10/11/2009          12/12/2009     02/02/2011      02/03/2011
```

Where all the dates are given in increasing value.But I am trying to get some `ADODB` functionality by which I can set the date values which are null to something greater than that record's last column date.

Say, as an exmple process#12 test1 date,test2 date,delivery date are`NULL`,so by .vbs script it should be set to `16/02/2012,17/02/2012,18/02/2012`.

**CODE:**

Option Explicit

```
Dim conn, cmd, rs
     Dim clauses(34), i
Dim xlApp, xlBook
Dim tempDate,LenDate


Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
With conn
.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
.ConnectionString = "Data Source=""D:\AravoVB\Final Scripts\GE_Wing_To_Wing_Report - Copy.xlsx"";" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes"""
.Open
End With
'tempDate=""
For i = 0 To 34
clauses(i) = "IIf(IsNull([Task" & i + 1 & " Start Date]),Date()+"& i &",[Task" & i + 1 & " Start Date]) < IIf(IsNull([Task" & i + 2 & " Start Date]),Date()+"& i &",[Task" & i + 2 & " Start Date])"
tempDate=tempDate & "NVL([Task" & i + 1 & " Start Date],Date()+"& i &"),"
Next
'LenDate=Len(tempDate)-1
'tempDate=Mid(tempDate,1,LenDate)
MsgBox(tempDate)

Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [GEWingToWingMay25$] WHERE [Business Process ID] NOT IN (" & "SELECT [Business Process ID] FROM [GEWingToWingMay25$] WHERE " & Join(clauses, " OR ") & ")"
MsgBox(cmd.CommandText)
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn 
Set rs = cmd.Execute

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = True
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
xlBook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset cmd.Execute
'xlBook.Sheets(1).Cells(1,25).Value=cmd.CommandText
```

Comment: @Tukai Why don't you write a `sub` in Sheet level to update all null dates in the range based on the previous date value?

Comment: @bonCodigo Because I then need to do then loop technique again,which would search over the 2000 rows and 160 columns,to do such comparisons.

Comment: I think you should show the code that you have, not just the spreadsheet content.

Comment: @Tomalak Please see the Code,I just pasted.Not the exactly like this,but simliar. I also not able to do this by this.Could you please help??

Answer (score 0):

You need an UPDATE statement instead of a SELECT statement. Specifcally something like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = _
    "UPDATE [GEWingToWingMay25$] " & _
    "SET [Task1 Start Date] = Now() " & _
    "WHERE [Business Process ID] NOT IN (" & _
        "SELECT [Business Process ID] " & _
        "FROM [GEWingToWingMay25$] " & _
        "WHERE " & Join(clauses, " OR ") & 
    ")"
```

Comment: please help me, I am in trouble for that! can't understood the way!

Comment: @VBSlover This is going to take a little more work and some more time. In short, you need to create a separate set of clauses for the updates. I'm assuming you only want to chage the date if there are values in the corresponding columns - for **TaskN Start Date** there should also be values in **TaskN Name** and the other **TaskN** columns.

Comment: Also, how do you want to treat an empty TaskN start date if the other TaskN columns are not empty?

Comment: The column names (`designdate`, `codingdate`, `test1 date`, test2 date`, `deliverdate`) in your sample data are different from those used by the code.

Comment: not needed only any of the TaskNcolumn has null value, then it should be updated by the date of its preceeding column Task(N-1) Date by 1.And the same for Task(n+1) will be having date as TaskN date +1, all in increasing order.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21577/discussion-between-vbslover-and-zev-spitz)

Comment: Could you please also help me here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001035/error-in-nvl-function-is-there-any-equivalent-function-like-nvl/14002876#comment19332840_14002876

Comment: Can you help me in the above linked post?