# Multiple array assignment to an excel range

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

Just out of curiosity ,I am asking you a question which is as below:

Suppose i do have an array A1(6)=(45,25,,36,88),A2(6)=(14,25,11),A3(6)=(11,21,20,25,48).Now can we put those array values with the help of a single statement like single array assignment to a row,as here all the rows to a range of an Excel, Say here "C1:R3" range.

***EDIT***

If I need to assign them to a row like R1<- A1 + A2 +A3,R2<- A1 + A2 +A3. Can you tell me how to this?

R1<- (45,25,,36,88),14,25,11,,,,11,21,20,25,48,) same for R2.

Thanks,

Comment: The second part is not entirely clear. Could you elaborate please? I can't quite understand which values you are wanting, and where you want them. Specifically, what do R1 and R2 refer to? Is A1 + A2 + A3 a concatenation of the arrays or a matrix addition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Dim A(2,5)
    For i = 0 to 5
        A(0, i) = A1(i)
        A(1, i) = A2(i)
        A(2, i) = A3(i)
    Next i
    Range("C1:R3").Value = A
```

**EDIT**

For second part, to the best of my understanding:

```
    Dim R(17)
    For i = 0 To 2
        For j = 0 To 5
            R(6 * i + j) = A(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i
    Range("C5:T5").Value = R
```

**EDIT 2**

Alternatively:

```
    Dim R
    R = Split(Join(A1, ",") & "," & Join(A2, ",") & "," & Join(A3, ","), ",")
    Range("C5:T5").Value = R
```

You can use any delimiter you like (if it's appropriate for your data).

Comment: its perfect thanks for that answer,now how to do the second part? See **EDIT**

Comment: Each row would contain merger values of the three arrays. Am I clear now?

Comment: any chance without `loop` to do the same?

Comment: Added an alternative, if you like.

Comment: that's the one i am looking for, can it be done for the first part also,without `Loop`?

Comment: I have not found a method to combine arrays into a matrix (you can get an array of arrays, but this does not paste to cells correctly).

You might be better off doing:

`Range("C1:T1").Value = A1`
`Range("C2:T2").Value = A2`
`Range("C3:T3").Value = A3`

Comment: May i have some idea on this from you,if you have no problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001035/error-in-nvl-function-is-there-any-equivalent-function-like-nvl#comment19332328_14001035